# GEE - Random Forest: how to calculate % variable importance?

Tags: random-forest, google-earth-engine

I'm trying to calculate the importance (in percentage) of each variable in my model (using smileRandomForest) in GEE.

```
var RFmodel = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(1000).train(trainingData, 'classID', predictionBands);

var var_imp = ee.Feature(null, ee.Dictionary(RFmodel.explain()).get('importance'));
```

In the example above, "var_imp" is a feature that has "importance" as a property. To calculate importance as %, I'm assuming I'll need to do something like:

Importance (%) = (variable importance value)/(total sum of all importance variables) * 100

Can someone help me to write a function for this? I'm relatively new to GEE and have no idea where to start. I've tried using aggregate_sum() at least to sum all variables, but "var_imp" isn't a FeatureCollection so it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work directly with the dictionary. Extract a list of the values and reduce it with a sum reducer to get the total importance. Then you can map over the importance dictionary and calculate the percentage of each band.

For future questions, please include a link to the code editor (use `Get Link`) and make sure all used assets are shared. It makes it easier to help you, increasing your chance of getting answers to your questions.

```
var importance = ee.Dictionary(
  classifier.explain().get('importance')
)
var totalImportance = importance.values().reduce(ee.Reducer.sum())
var importancePercentage = importance.map(function (band, importance) {
  return ee.Number(importance).divide(totalImportance).multiply(100)
})
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/bd63aa319a37516d924a6d8c391ab076